# What is QP layer?

Tags: mysql, database-administration, querypath

From **blogs.innodb.com**: [InnoDB Memcached with Binlog Capability](http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/10/innodb-memcached-with-binlog-capability/)

> In our earlier Labs release, we presented a MySQL NoSQL solution through InnoDB Memcached Daemon Plugin (see earlier Calvin’s and my posts). That earlier release allows the Memcached Plugin directly interacting with InnoDB, completely bypassing MySQL optimizer and ***`QP layers`***. It differs with another popular MySQL NoSQL solution, HandlerSocket, by skipping even the Handler API layer and directly access the InnoDB through InnoDB APIs. Thus, in theory, it would be simpler and more efficient.

What are ***`QP Layers`***?

Searching did not yield me any good results. The closest I came to was ***`Query Path`***. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it means Query Processing which includes parsing, optimizing, etc.

Comment: You probably are right as it involves a separate process to resolve it: [MySQL Query Processing Rules](http://cherry.world.edoors.com/CnEFCeWtnsn8)
Here is another answer [`Query Parsing`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8755/4735)

Which are pretty close in meaning to each other.